# Exercise about Buffer Overflow

Tags: c, buffer, stack-overflow

I'm trying to find vulnerability in the following code, and i'm just guessing that it can be exploited with buffer overflow, but unfortunately i don't know where to begin with.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TABLELEN 7
int table[] = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17};

void loadTable(int *hashtable) {
int i;
for (i = 0; i < TABLELEN; i++) {
hashtable[i] = table[i];
  } 
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int array[8];
 int index;
 int value;
 if (argc < 3) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Not enough args\n");
    return -1;
 }
 loadTable(array);
 index = (int) strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
 value = (int) strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 16);
 printf("Updating table value at index %d with %d: previous value was %d\n",
 index, value, array[index]); 
 array[index] = value;
 printf("The updated table is:\n");
 for (index = 0; index < TABLELEN; index++) {
    printf("%d: %d\n", index, array[index]);
 }
  return 0;
 }
```

I'm trying to find way to exploit the part where the array size is 8 but only 7 elements have been declared. I'm not looking for the exact solution but any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: As you don't check the value of `index` before using it, one can call your program with a value higher than 7 to write `value` at an unexpected position to corrupt the stack. [Here is an article about stack based buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_buffer_overflow).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buffer overflow can be caused in this case as you do not check what is the value of `index` variable, after you convert it to `long`. Later you use the statement :

```
array[index] = value;
```

but you have declared `array` as :

```
int array[8];
```

which means that your `array's` indexes will start from `0` and reach up to `7`. So if `index` is greater than `7`, buffer overflow can be caused.